# for loop for every matrices in a list

Tags: r, list, dataframe, for-loop

I am trying to apply the following for-loop to every matrices in the list `per_d` and create a new list called `per_hole`. I am not sure how to do this, should I use lapply?

Thank you very much in advance for your helps!

```
per_hole <- per_d
  for (i in 1:S) {
    for (j in 1:t){
  if (per_hole [i,j] > CS) {
    per_hole [i,j] <- per_hole [i,j] - rnorm (1, mean = 1, sd = 0.5)
  } else {
    per_hole [i,j] <- per_hole [i,j] + rnorm (1, mean = 1, sd = 0.5)
  }}}
```

codes for reproduction

```
N <- 1
CS <- 10.141 
S <- seq (7.72,13,0.807) 
t <- 15
l <- length (S)
m0 <- 100 
exps <- c(0.2, 0.5, 0.9, 1.5, 2) 
sd_per <- c(0.2, 0.5, 0.8, 1.3, 1.8) 
sd_noise <- 3 


per <- lapply(sd_per, function(x){ 
  per <- matrix(nrow = length(S)*N, ncol = t+1)
  for (i in 1:dim(per)[1]) {
    for (j in 1:t+1){
      per [,1] <- replicate (n = N, S)
      per [i,j] <- round (abs (rnorm (1, mean = per[i,1], sd =x)),digits=3)
      colnames(per) <- c('physical',paste('t', 1:15, sep = ""))
      per <- as.data.frame (per)
    }
  }
  per <- per [,-1]
  return(per)
}
)  
names(per) <- paste("per", seq_along(sd_per), sep = "")

per_d <- lapply(per, function(x){ 
  per_d <- abs (x - 10.141) 
}
)  
names(per_d) <- paste("per_d", seq_along(sd_per), sep = "")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try

```
per_hole <- lapply(per_d,function(x) x + ifelse(x>CS,-1,1)*rnorm(prod(dim(x)),1,0.5))
```

or

```
per_hole <- lapply(per_d, function(x) x + rnorm(prod(dim(x)), 1-2*(x > CS), 0.5))
```

Comment: Hi, this solution is really clever! thank you! May I also ask how should I do if I want 'if x belongs to row 4, returns 0? I tried `per_hole <- lapply(per_d,function(x) x + ifelse(x %in% x[4,],0,ifelse(x>CS,-1,1))*rnorm(prod(dim(x)),1,0.5))`

Comment: @KennyYu Try `per_hole <- lapply(per_d, function(x) x + rnorm(prod(dim(x)), 1 - 2 * (x > CS), 0.5)*replace(rep(1,nrow(x),4,0)))`

Comment: this error message popped up ' Error in replace(rep(1, nrow(x), 4, 0)) : argument "values" is missing, with no default'. I guess it is because per_d is a list with several data frames in it?

Comment: @KennyYu Sorry,, my bad. I had a typo. Here is the one that might work `replace(rep(1,nrow(x)),4,0)`

Comment: Thank you so much!! It worked!! If you don't mind, could you explain briefly how this work? I don't quite understand what happen in `replace`

Comment: @KennyYu `replace(rep(1,nrow(x)),4,0)` creates a vector of 1s except for the fourth place. We use this as a mask to make the 4th row zeros.